# Sapper/Svelte - need @html included content to invoke component

Tags: javascript, svelte, sapper

I'm building a site using `sapper` that uses the `[slug].svelte` convention for individual blog entries.  The blog content comes out of a (simulated) database, and contains html.

The html is included at the bottom, like so:

```
...
<div class="content">
  {@html post.html}
</div>
...
```

All well and good, it renders the html just peachy.

However, consider the following:

In the `[slug].svelte` file:

```
import AComponent from '../../components/AComponent.svelte'
```

And, in the included html rendered inside the `{@html post.html}`:

```
<p>yada yada yada</p>
<AComponent prop="data" />
<p>More yada yada yada...</p>
```

`AComponent` doesn't get instantiated or invoked.

Is there a way to make this happen?  Or am I trying to do something not possible?

(I know the component is ok - it's been tested in another file with complete html.)

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that's possible with the `@html` directive alone.

From [the docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#html):

> The expression should be valid standalone HTML — `{@html "<div>"}content{@html "</div>"}` will not work, because  is not valid HTML.

Since `<AComponent prop="data" />` is a Svelte component and not standalone HTML, it won't instantiate itself when using `@html`.

However, you could wrangle together a solution using [`<svelte:component>`](https://svelte.dev/docs#svelte_component) to render a component from string content dynamically.

Here's a quick proof of concept in the [Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/bdb98bc23bfa4535bd595ab7aa321bc0?version=3.31.0). There's a bunch of edge cases left uncovered, but it shows that it's possible. I've also pasted the code below.

```
<script>
    import ComponentA from './ComponentA.svelte';
    import ComponentB from './ComponentB.svelte';
    
    let raw = `<p>yada yada yada</p>
<ComponentA name="testing" />
<p>More yada yada yada...</p>`;
    
    $: rawLines = raw.split('\n');
    
    function getComponent(line) {
        const componentName = line.split(' ')[0].substring(1);
        switch (componentName) {
            case 'ComponentA':
                return ComponentA;
            case 'ComponentB':
                return ComponentB;
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    function getComponentProps(line) {
        const props = line.split(' ').slice(1, -1);
        const kvPairs = props.map(p => p.replaceAll('"', '').split('='));
        return Object.fromEntries(kvPairs);
    }
</script>

<textarea bind:value={raw} />
{#each rawLines as line}
    {#if line[1] === line[1].toUpperCase()}
        <svelte:component this={getComponent(line)} {...getComponentProps(line)}></svelte:component>
    {:else}
        {@html line}
    {/if}
{/each}
```

Comment: Interesting idea.  I wound up writing a pre-processor to inject the pieces of code into a template file, and the write the named file out into the 'src/routes/blog/' folder.  The svelte compiler takes it from there as it normally would.  Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it works.  It loses the live update ability on edit, so I have to do a recompile when I make an edit.  Also, I'm thinking I can call other preprocessors from that, such as a markdown processor.